# Как определить, принадлежит ли IP-адрес дата-центру?

Tags: ip

Как определить принадлежит ли IP адрес дата центру, или это обычный IP провайдера?
Может есть какие-нибудь базы айпишек ДЦ США и Европа.

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/91278/

Comment: Для начала надо определиться что именно понимается под понятием "дата-центр".

Comment: @newman
Задача определить по айпи - живой пользователь или айпи принадлежит серверу.

Comment: @rd2d2 Ну вот у меня на работе куча серверов с белой статикой Ростелекома. Что Вам даст знание того, что я в пуле Ростелека? Высока вероятность, что  я - домашний пользователь, но тем не менее это сервер. Или в ДЦ сидит админ и от скуки гуляет по Инету. Или же контора лазит в Инет через VPN до ДЦ. IP от ДЦ, но это живые люди. А вообще, надо смотреть по whois. У серьёзных ДЦ есть свои AS. Но немало мелких ДЦ, которые сидят в общем пуле магистральщиков без собственных AS.

Comment: А по какой информации в whois можно определить?

Answer (score 1):

Можно просто [whois](https://2ip.ru/whois/) посмотреть. Насчет ЦОД точно не знаю, но провайдеров показывает...